# Front camera and flash in Red laser SDK

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I wanted to know whether do we have an option to scan the bar code using front camera in red laser android sdk? also how to turn on the flash? Is any document or sample app is available for the above requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the Android RedLaser SDK are you using? try Updating/Downloading the most recent stable version. It works fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these features have been added to the 3.0 version of the Android RedLaser SDK. The RLSample app, included in the SDK package, demos both of these features.